# Excel Make Formula not update when moving a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculated-columns

I am looking for a trick to make this formula :

```
=IF(I3>=50%;"Y";"N")
```

not adjust when moving content of column I. So that when I insert a column in the left of column "I" (so column I becomes clear now), the formula is still the same as the above and NOT :

```
=IF(J3>=50%;"Y";"N")
```

and when I delete the content of I it doesn't become :

```
=IF(#REF!>=50%;"Y";"N")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I thought the dollar sign can help you fix these. so equation becomes =IF($I1>=50%,"Y","N")

Comment: No me too, when I add a column to the left of I, the formula just becomes `=($J3>=50%,"Y","N")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
=IF(index(3:3; 0; 9)>=50%; "Y"; "N")
```